# PenTesting as a career guidlines

Tags: penetration-test, career

it's my first post so bear with me.
I live in England and am currently studying A-levels at specialist IT school and I am doing BTEC IT, Maths, Computer Science(learning c#) and Product design. I have done a few MOS's and plan to take an MTA sometime soon. This is all well and good but I am looking for a career in security (in specific PenTesting). Any ideas on how to start my career towards my goal. Do I need to go to uni? can I get an apprenticeship? what are some useful website/reputable companies that could help me start learning?

Thanks in advance,
Simon

Comment: Welcome, Simon. There are many, many questions of this type on this site. Unfortunately, as it stands, this question is too broad for this forum. The best answer is to ask the companies in your area what *they* require, and start your research there.